How to make flex child item stretch with sibling overflowing item?
I have a flex container, and I am trying to make the footer in it be full width, but when the sibling table overflows, the footer is not following the new width of the container, how to overcome that behaviour?


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">
    <button>
      Load more
    </button>
  </div>
</div>




You can remove width 100% in .footer

Use CSS grid instead and you will get the behavior you want by default:


.container {
  display: grid;
  align-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">
    <button>
      Load more
    </button>
  </div>
</div>




You made it seem easy :)

Change width : 100% to min-width:100%.


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">
    <button>
      Load more
    </button>
  </div>
</div>




Your snippet works and I thought I got a snippet similar to what I have in my project, but here it doesn't work, the footer is at the right of the table (I don't know why, can't even notice any other css applied to the elements). And only when I remove the flex-wrap: wrap from the container the footer goes down, but then the min-width: 100% doesn't work.

Is it possible to remove the flex-wrap: wrap from the snippet and make it keep working?

Perhaps position: sticky; will be useful:


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="footer">
    <button>
      Load more
    </button>
  </div>
</div>



